# What is a valid return type for a pointer function in C?

Tags: c, pointers

The function `*getString()` is intended to return the address of the local variable `a`. However, it gives a warning: return from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types].

What would be a valid return type for this function?

```
#include <stdio.h>
char *getString()
{
  char a[] = "Hello World"; 
  return &a; 
}     
int main()
{
  printf("%s", getString());  
  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `return a` would get rid of this warning, but returning a pointer to a local array is invalid.

Comment: You might first want to spend some thoughts on the lifetime of your locall variable that you return a pointer to. It might not exist as long as you assume.

Comment: The type of `&a` is `char (*)[12]`, not `char *`. Arrays naturally *decays* to pointers to their first element, so e.g. `a` is equivalent to `&a[0]`, which has the type `char *`. But the life-time of the array ends when the function returns, making any pointer to it or its elements will be invalid.

Comment: declaring char *a instead of char a[] seems to solve the problem but if array data types automatically decay into pointers what's the difference?

Comment: You should understand the consequences of declaring it as `char *`. It makes it to point to a static *string literal*, which cannot be modified.

Comment: All literal strings are really arrays of characters (including the null-terminator) stored in read.only memory, and whose life-time last the full run-time of the programs execution. When you have `char *a = "Hello World";` then you have a pointer to the first character in that array. That pointer will never become invalid. When you have `char a[] = "Hello World";` you make your own local array and initialize it, it will be separate from the literal string.